# Transform Row Values to Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table of customer contacts and their role. Simplified example below.

```
customer | role        | userid
----------------------------
1        | Support     | 123
1        | Support     | 456
1        | Procurement | 567
...
```

desired output

```
customer | Support1 | Support2 | Support3 | Support4 | Procurement1 | Procurement2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 123      | 456      | null     | null     | 567          | null
2        | 123      | 456      | 12333    | 45776    | 888          | 56723
```

So dynamically create number of required columns based on how many user are in that role. It's a small number of roles. Also I can assume max 5 user in that same role. Which means worst case I need to generate 5 columns for each role. The userids don't need to be in any particular order.

My current approach is getting 1 userid per role/customer. Then a second query pulls another id that wasn't part of first results set. And so on. But that way I have to statically create 5 queries. It works. But I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way? Dynamically creating needed columns.

Example of pulling one user per role:

```
SELECT customer,role,
(SELECT  top 1 userid
FROM temp as tmp1
where tmp1.customer=tmp2.customer and tmp1.role=tmp2.role
) as userid
 FROM temp as tmp2
 group by customer,role
 order by customer,role
```

SQL create with dummy data

```
create table temp
    (
      customer int,
      role nvarchar(20),
      userid int
    )
    
    insert into temp values (1,'Support',123)
    insert into temp values (1,'Support',456)
    insert into temp values (1,'Procurement',567)
    insert into temp values (2,'Support',123)
    insert into temp values (2,'Support',456)
    insert into temp values (2,'Procurement',888)
    insert into temp values (2,'Support',12333)
    insert into temp values (2,'Support',45776)
    insert into temp values (2,'Procurement',56723)
```

Comment: Hi, MS SQL Server. Just tagged

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adapt your approach slightly if you want to avoid getting into the realm of programming user defined table functions (which is what you would need in order to generate columns dynamically). You don't mention which SQL database variant you are using (SQL Server, PostgreSQL, ?). I'm going to make the assumption that it supports some form of string aggregation feature (they pretty much all do), but the syntax for doing this will vary, so you will probably have to adjust the code to your circumstances. You mention that the number of roles is small (5-ish?). The proposed solution is to generate a comma-separated list of user ids, one for each role, using common table expressions (CTEs) and the LISTAGG (variously named STRING_AGG, GROUP_CONCAT, etc. in other databases) function.

```
WITH tsupport 
     AS (SELECT customer, 
                Listagg(userid, ',') AS "Support" 
         FROM   temp 
         WHERE  ROLE = 'Support' 
         GROUP  BY customer), 
     tprocurement 
     AS (SELECT customer, 
                Listagg(userid, ',') AS "Procurement" 
         FROM   temp 
         WHERE  ROLE = 'Procurement' 
         GROUP  BY customer)
 --> tnextrole... 
 --> AS (SELECT ... for additional roles 
 -->            Listagg...
SELECT a.customer, 
       "Support", 
       "Procurement" 
 -->   "Next Role"  etc.
FROM   tsupport a 
       JOIN tprocurement b 
         ON a.customer = b.customer 
 -->   JOIN tNextRole ...
```

Fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=32797573ce18b9a07456228a060a3ddf) with a result that appears as below based on your dummy data:

[image: Output based on your sample]